# Extra arguments for Factory Girl

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, factory-bot

I need to pass extra arguments to factory girl to be used in a callback. Something like this (but more complex really):

```
Factory.define :blog do |blog|
  blog.name "Blah"

  blog.after_create do |blog|
    blog.posts += sample_posts
    blog.save!
  end
end
```

and then create it with something like this:

```
Factory.create(:blog, :sample_posts => [post1, post2])
```

Any ideas how to do it?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

This is now possible without any "hacks" thanks to transient attributes ([see comment on issue #49](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/issues/49#issuecomment-3890296))

example:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    transient do
      bar_extension false
    end
    name {"foo #{' bar' if bar_extension}"}
  end
end

# Factory(:user).name = "foo"
# Factory(:user, :bar_extension => true).name = "foo bar"
```

For Factory Girl versions < 5.0:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    ignore do
      bar_extension false
    end
    name {"foo #{' bar' if bar_extension}"}
  end
end

# Factory(:user).name = "foo"
# Factory(:user, :bar_extension => true).name = "foo bar"
```

Comment: Useful set of docs here, including how to access a transient attribute from an after_create or other block: https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md

Answer (score 2):

One option would be to create a virtual accessor for extra posts that the `after_create` hook checks:

```
class Blog
  has_many :posts
  attr_accessible :name, :title, ... # DB columns
  attr_accessor   :sample_posts      # virtual column
end

Factory.define :blog do |blog|
  blog.name 'Blah'

  blog.after_create do |b|
    b.posts += b.sample_posts
    b.save!
  end
end

Factory(:blog, :sample_posts => [post1, post2])
```

Comment: For my example that would work, my real case is a little more complicated. Besides, I wouldn't like polluting models for the sake of FactoryGirl's limitations. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: You only need to pollute the model in your `test` environment. In fact, you can do it right there in `factories.rb`.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently, this is not possible at the moment without workarounds that require modifying the model itself. This bug is reported in: http://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/issues#issue/49

Comment: issue #49 was closed recently, see my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9305231/745359)

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be to use `build` instead of `create` and add `:autosave` to the collection:

```
class Blog
  has_many :posts, :autosave => true
end

Factory.define :blog do |blog|
  blog.name 'Blah'
  blog.posts { |_| [Factory.build(:post)] }
end

Factory(:blog, :posts => [post1, post2])
#or
Factory.build(:blog, :posts => [unsavedPost1, unsavedPost2])
```

Answer (score 1):

if you are opening the class inside the factorygirl file, i suggest doing it like

```
require "user"
class User
  attr :post_count
end
```

so that you are opening the class, instead of overwriting it